# df and Dolphin say home is full, partition manager says there is 1 TB free

Tags: disk-usage

I recently replaced the disk for my home partition with a larger one. It is now double the size. However my system still thinks it's full.

This is correct and it is what I see in parted too:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1,8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  1000M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0   1,8T  0 part /home
```

Dolphin or `df` can't seem to see the full disk

```
$  df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       881G  836G  117M 100% /home
```

[image: parted screenshot]

How to fix this?

Comment: How did you resize this partition? Looks like you resized the partition but not the file-system. Please add additional information via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1235810/edit) to your question.

Comment: edited. Don't be confused with sda1, it's empty, the OS is on a different physical drive.

Comment: So how did you copy your data to the new disk?

Comment: With dd. It finished without errors. It has the correct size (disk usage of new drive is equal to old disk usage) and some random files I checked are there and working .

Comment: exact command please!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You copied your old file-system to the bigger partition. This does not change the file-system-size.

You need to adapt the file-system-size to the new partition-size. To do that run

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2
```

Please take a look at `man resize2fs`.

Comment: How comes parted can lsblk can see the correct size and usage?

Comment: Parted is a tool to manipulate partition tables and reads from partition table. lsblk also reads from partition table to determine partition size. You need to understand that partition and file-system are not the same thing. The partition is just a defined space on the disk. The partition may or may not contain a file-system. Read the first chapters in `man resize2fs`, it should really help you to understand more.

Comment: Phantastic. That solved the issue and thanks for the explanation.