# Dolphin showing wrong free disk space

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, hard-drive, disk-usage

Have installed Kubuntu 20.04 on a new hard drive and before that have made a copy of the old home partition by `cp /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb3`. Whereby *sdb3* was the new home partition on the new 1TB hard drive (now sda3).
At the installation of Kubuntu 20.04 I mounted sda3 as /home which is working fine (the old system was Kubuntu 18.04).

On the old drive the home partition was about 80GB, the new one has 320GB (from this only 45GB are used).

I have partitioned the new drive with KDE Partition Manager with a ***gpt*** Table.
The old one had an *ms-dos* table.
Now Dolphin file manager shows only about 25GB free disk space for the home partition (which was probably approximate the number of the old free drive space …

KDE Partition Manager displays the correct free space (but has a question mark icon on sda3, 2,1,4).
What to do to make Dolphin showing up the right free disk space and being able to use it?

Comment: Is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1235810/590937) helpful in any way?

Answer (score 2):

You *copied* the file system when you ran `cp /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb3`. That means the file system is not aware the size has changed.

How to grow it depends on what filesystem you use. Run `mount` to show all filesystems and file system type.

If it's ext3/4, simply run `sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb3` to resize it.

Comment: resize2fs resize the file system only, sound good. But is that affecting the files, will files be deleted..?

Comment: Resizing file system is normally not destructive, but as always, things happen, so you should always have a backup of data anyway.

Comment: It worked, looks almost like being non destructive.
After the process it was even 42 files more but 27 sub-folders less... from 93,597 files and 3,385 sub-folders.

Comment: Just KDE Partition Manager shows  question mark icons on the Mount Point column... maybe an incorrect fstab entry ..?